# Is it possible to use collective.alias in a 3.1.7 plone?

Tags: python, plone, buildout

Is it possible? I would like to install it in a 3.1.7 Plone instance, but don't want to enter the buildout incompatible versions hell.

I tried in my machine, adding along with `collective.alias`

```
extends =
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.0a2
```

and

```
[versions]
plone.recipe.plone = 3.1.7 
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 3.6
```

But starts downloading a lot of stuff, until it downloaded Plone 4 egg itself as a dependency.

I couldn't find a source of really pinned versions for 3.17 that would make possible to install collective.alias, that's why I'm asking this question, I would like to know if anyone at SO had a similar problem.

Comment: Have you made a copy of your buildout and tried it out? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Yes. I've update my question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collective.alias depends on dexterity. Dexterity is not fully supported on plone3. And  I guess you will need to upgrade to 3.3.

Dexterity needs Plone4.1 to play well with archetypes content and have all plone feature (history, diff, lock, ...)

try this:

```
extends=
http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.0?plone=3.3.5
```